Why did American usage of the word "cancellable" spike around 1940?
While trying to recall whether or not American English doubles the L in cancellable, I pulled up this Google Ngram.
What caused usage of the word cancellable to spike around 1940? Since the spike occurs only in the American English corpus and not the British English corpus, we can probably assume the cause is specific to the USA. It's proven to be a rather tricky thing to google.

You do know that you can get Google Books to search for specific words in specific time frames? The usage of cancellable seems restricted to the insurance industry, rather than being a general English language usage, and therefore any explanation is likely to be found in economic or legal history rather than the history of the English language. It's not surprising that the US insurance industry saw changes firstly c. 1929 and then c. 1941. Check a US history book.

"Canceled" comes up often in software. As an American software engineer, I find that a lot of my compatriots accidentally or unknowingly use the British "cancelled," or overlook or don't care about the distinction. It doesn't mean they're "right," but I do feel like US/UK spelling distinctions are becoming more flexible.

non-cancellable disability insurance was only really introduced in the US in 1920, as reflected by that chart. But most likely a spike in 1941 was influenced by WW2, Pearl Harbour, and the consequent realization that good health isn't guaranteed.

@AndyBonner Fifty and a hundred years ago we had no software scolds, so back then we naturally doubled the final consonant in more places than cisatlantic algorithmic scolds “allow” these days in words like levelled, programming, cancellation, signalled and many more. There’s no freedom of choice left in American publishing because you cannot appeal your case to software. You just have to buckle under and do whatever these tyrant scolds demand you do: “Just say no!” At least this cybernetic antiïnclusivity madness hasn’t spread to Canada—yet.
